# Why does the compiler choose the copy ctor after calling move

Tags: c++, copy-constructor, rvalue-reference, move-constructor

For the following code, I know that because I implement a copy constructor the default move is blocked by the compiler, what I don't understand is why the compiler choose the copy constructor, and not issuing an error?
Can a rvalue reference be the parameter for a reference function if no rvalue ref function exists?
If not, what do happens here?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A{
    public:

        A(){printf("constructor\n");}
        A(const A& a){printf("copy constructor");}
};

int main()
{ 
    A a;
    A b = std::move(a);
    return 1; 
}
```

The output is:

```
constructor
copy constructor
```

Thanks

Comment: *"Can a ravlue reference be the parameter for a reference function if no rvalue ref function exists?"* -- Yes.

Comment: Just to be sure, ravlue reference can be a parameter for a lvalue reference function parameter? Thanks!

Comment: @DsCpp Not quite.  The can be passed to `const &` parameters.  related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102728/why-is-it-allowed-to-pass-r-values-by-const-reference-but-not-by-normal-refrence

Comment: You can plainly see in your own example that it can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is that *rvalue expressions* can be bound to function parameters that are `const` *lvalue references*.

---

Also note that `const` *rvalue expressions* cannot be bound to rvalue references:

```
class A{
    public:    
        A(){printf("constructor\n");}
        A(const A& a){printf("copy constructor");}
        A(A&&) = default; // <-- has move ctor
}; 

int main()
{ 
    const A a; // <-- const!
    A b = std::move(a); // <-- copy not move!!!
    return 1; 
}
```

The code above still calls the copy constructor, even though there is a move constructor.

Comment: That's a great addition to the question, Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`std::move` will take your named value and turn it into an rvalue expression, nothing more.

And, just like for any other rvalue, if it can't be moved, it'll be copied.

An rvalue of type `T` can be bound to a `const T&` just fine.