# std::atomic passed as a const reference to a non-atomic type

Tags: c++, thread-safety, stdatomic

Let's say I have this application:

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

void do_something(const std::atomic<bool>& stop) {
    while (!stop) {
        std::cout << "Doing stuff..." << std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}

int main() {
    std::atomic<bool> stop { false };

    std::thread wait([&stop] { 
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));
        stop = true;
    });

    do_something(stop);

    wait.join();
}
```

This works as expected. The main thread loops until the `wait` thread sets `stop`. As far as I know, there's no real issues with this application since it's using an `std::atomic<bool>` for synchronization between the threads.

However, I can break the application by changing the signature of `do_something` to this:

```cpp
void do_something(const bool& stop);
```

This still compiles without any warnings, but the loop in `do_something` never exits. Conceptually, I understand why this happens. `do_something` is accepting a const reference to a non-atomic value, so it would be reasonable to optimize the function to something like:

```cpp
void do_something(const bool& stop) {
    if (!stop) {
        while(true) {
            std::cout << "Doing stuff..." << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }
}
```

What's confusing to me is why the modified application compiles at all. I wouldn't expect to be able to pass an `std::atomic` value into a function expecting a const reference to a non-atomic type. I haven't looked at the standard, but I don't see anything on cppreference that suggests this conversion is allowed.

Am I misunderstanding something here? Is this just some quirk of `std::atomic` that's not obvious to me from the documentation?

Comment: Is it really the case that the compiler is allowed to optimise here? In a multithreaded environment, the stop value can be changed even if it is read by a const reference in the meantime, can it not? https://onlinegdb.com/menLSBacx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because there is an implicit conversion when you call
`do_something(const bool &stop)`
while passing an `std::atomic<bool>`

It translates to:

`do_something(static_cast<bool>(stop.operator bool()));`

As you can see here : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/operator_T

You actually tell the compiler to load the value once, right at the time of the call.

Comment: Interesting. I saw that operator but couldn't really make sense of it.

So in my example, it's not even a case of `do_something` not seeing an update to the reference. It's just getting a reference to an entirely new copy of the value?

Comment: take a look at your code C++ insights : https://cppinsights.io/s/fa1ca15e

Comment: you tell the compiler the value won't change by specifying the `const` keyword, so the compiler assumes the value won't ever change. Actually, if you remove the `const` keyword, it won't even compile, because it makes no sense.

Comment: In case someone stumbles across this and doesn't follow (like I didn't): It makes no sense without `const` because `operator bool()` is providing an rvalue as the argument to `do_something`. You can't pass an rvalue to a function by non-const reference, but you can by const reference. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36102728/why-is-it-allowed-to-pass-r-values-by-const-reference-but-not-by-normal-referenc